# I could not merge a branch to master in Git

Tags: git

What does (master *+|MERGING) mean?

```
**Owner (master *+|MERGING)** asteroids $ git branch
  coins
  easy-mode
* master
**Owner (master *+|MERGING) asteroids $ git merge master coins**
error: 'merge' is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree,
hint: and then use 'git add/rm <file>' as
hint: appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit,
hint: or use 'git commit -a'.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
Owner (master *+|MERGING) asteroids $
```

Comment: It means you’re in the middle of a merge already. See `git status`. If you want to cancel whichever merge, use `git merge --abort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently in the middle of a merge.  This may mean that you were already performing a merge, but forgot.  You're now attempting to merge *again*, but Git is preventing you from doing that since you already have a pending operation.

In this state, there are a few things you can do:

- Finish the merge (hopefully after you've resolved your conflict) via `git commit`
- Stop the merge via `git merge --abort` or `git reset --hard HEAD`.  I'd recommend the former form as opposed to the latter, since doing a hard-reset will remove *any* changes in your staging area.